# beginner panda change row data based upon code

Tags: python, pandas

I'm a beginner in panda and python, trying to learn it.
I would like to iterate over panda rows, to apply simple coded logic.
Instead of fancy mapping functions, I just want simple coded logic.
So then I can easily adapt it later for other coded logic rules as well.

In my dataframe `dc`,
I like to check if column `AgeUnkown == 1`   (or `>0` )
And if so it should move the value of column `Age` to `AgeUnknown`.
And then make `Age` equal to 0.0
I tried various combinations of my below code but it won't work.

```
# using a row  reference #########
for index, row in dc.iterrows():
   r = row['AgeUnknown']
   if (r>0):
     w = dc.at[index,'Age']
     dc.at[index,'AgeUnknown']=w
     dc.at[index,'Age']=0
```

Another attempt

```
for index in dc.index:
  r = dc.at[index,'AgeUnknown'].[0]  # also tried .sum  here
    if (r>0):
      w= dc.at[index,'Age']
      dc.at[index,'AgeUnknown']=w
      dc.at[index,'Age']=0
```

Also tried

```
  if(dc[index,'Age']>0    #wasnt allowed either
```

Why isn't this working as far as I understood a dataframe should be able to be addressed like above.

Comment: Since you say that you are trying to learn `pandas`, I think an important piece of advice is that there is *almost always* a more efficient solution than iterating over your dataframe, and iteration is in fact generally bad practice. Your question could also be much improved by including a [mcve].

Comment: I learn panda on the go, the more advanced funtions are not yet in my reach.
but as i practice i pick things up, in this case though i want to be flexible readability of code is what i usally prefer. It can be a bit slower, but for neural networks this not where to most time is spended.

Comment: what is your error message? it isn't clear where the error might be occurring.  Make sure the datatypes of Age and AgeUnknown columns are actually integer/float (dc.dtypes).

Comment: My error message is Invalid index to scalar variable.
It goes wrong in the line if( r>0 ):

Comment: thats the error for your top example??

Comment: at least to get you pointed in some direction your code for the top example should theoretically work.  The method in the second example should be avoided, it will be much slower (and you shouldn't need to index with the [0] if the indexes are unique) good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I realize you requested a solution involving iterating the df, but I thought I'd provide one that I think is more traditional.

A non-iterating solution to your problem is something like this- 1) get all the indexes that meet your criteria 2) set those indexes of the df to what you want.

```
# indexes where column AgeUnknown is >0
inds = dc[dc['AgeUnknown'] > 0].index.tolist()
# change the indexes of AgeUnknown to to the Age column
dc.loc[inds, 'AgeUnknown'] = dc.loc[inds, 'Age']
# change the Age to 0 at those indexes
dc.loc[inds, 'Age'] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for this,though i ask for a traverse solution, otherwise i would have accepted is as a solution. The point is i want to know how to traverse it, and reading setting data..in a more manual coded way.

Comment: i tried and it gives the following error : cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Comment: if you go this method, make sure your indexes are unique values, this has caused me problems many times (just something to watch for in pandas in general)- it can have strange results otherwise.

Comment: I figured out why you got the error, I had "df" instead of dc on line 3